# Database is not updated ADO.Net

Tags: ado.net

I have a customer class in my program and a customer table in an access database, i want to update customer balance in the database by given value.
I wrote all statements which seems to be correct, but unfortunately the database isn't affected.
This is the method which I use to update the DB
thanks in advance

```
public static bool UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
   bool EditSucceeded = false;
   string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\GarageProTuning.accdb;";

   using (OleDbConnection _con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
      string commandText = "UPDATE Customer SET Balance=@Balance WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID";

      using (OleDbCommand _cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, _con))
      {
         _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customer.CustomerID);
         _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", customer.Balance);
         _con.Open();
         int rowsAffected = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (rowsAffected > 0)
            EditSucceeded = true;
         _con.Close();
      }
   }
   return EditSucceeded;
}
```

Comment: Why are you closing your connection twice?

Comment: I want to add a notice, when I rewrote the commandtext with static values(without parameters) it updates the DB Successfully

Comment: Try moving `_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", customer.Balance);` above `_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customer.CustomerID);`.

Comment: Yeahh, thank you Brian, it works. still don't know why is the order affect the statement. I want to mark ur comment as answer, I am new to stackoverflow, how can I do this

Comment: I will add an answer that you can accept/upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
public static bool UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
   bool EditSucceeded = false;
   string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\GarageProTuning.accdb;";

   using (OleDbConnection _con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
      string commandText = "UPDATE Customer SET Balance=@Balance WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID";

      using (OleDbCommand _cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, _con))
      { 
         _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customer.CustomerID);
         _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", customer.Balance);
         _con.Open();
         int rowsAffected = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (rowsAffected > 0)
            EditSucceeded = true;
         _con.Close();
      }
   }
   return EditSucceeded;
}
```

What you need is:

```
public static bool UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
   bool EditSucceeded = false;
   string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\GarageProTuning.accdb;";

   using (OleDbConnection _con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
      string commandText = "UPDATE Customer SET Balance=@Balance WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID";

      using (OleDbCommand _cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, _con))
      { 
         _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", customer.Balance);  // Explanation below
         _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customer.CustomerID);
         _con.Open();
         int rowsAffected = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (rowsAffected > 0)
            EditSucceeded = true;
         _con.Close();
      }
   }
   return EditSucceeded;
}
```

[OleDbCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) are a *very particular* animal when it comes to how they are added/processed.  From the documentation I linked:

> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

In a nutshell, you **must** add your parameters in the *same* order that they appear in your command text.